# How does cutting into a cake tell it's a boy when blue candies come out?

Tags: plot-explanation, this-is-us

In "This is us", when they cut into the cake in Season 3, Episode 10, "The Last Seven Weeks", Toby and Kate saw blue candies spill out of the cut cake.

They then concluded the sex of the unborn baby and that they have a boy.

I don't understand. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[The color blue is associated with boy babies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_historical_sources_for_pink_and_blue_as_gender_signifiers), at least in the US.**

In the US, blue is considered the stereotypical color for boy babies, and pink for girl babies. This is expressed often in boys being given blue things to where; while girls are given pink things to wear.

In regards to cutting a cake specifically, this was an example of a "[Gender reveal party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_reveal)". At such parties, something will be revealed, often the inside of a cake, that will be blue if they are having a boy, or pink if they are having a girl.

Comment: Just to add, the blue for boys/pink for girls thing used to be reversed in the not too distant past.

Comment: I thought it had been that way my whole life, and I'm 50 years old! Do you know when it was reversed?

Comment: @BrettFromLA This is discussed (though without a lot of details) in my first link.

Comment: interesting... never thought there was ever any other way (until so many mother's starting using gender nuetral colors, like green and yellow).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you're having a boy the normal color is blue and when you're having a girl, the candies would have been pink. That's just the 2 colors people have been using for years. A lot of people get a baby room done all in blue if they're having a boy or all pink if they are having a girl. Over time, people started using these two colors. Hope that helped :)